# Is it possible to define word boundary character set in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to replace some strings in perl, which start with a `$` character and end with a `)`.   So for example replace `$(FOO)` with `FOO`.   I DON'T want to match something like `$(FOO)_BLAH` or `BLAH_$(FOO)` or $(FOO)$(BAR), but I do want to match the inner part of `$($(FOO))`.   I cannot use `\b` in my regex as neither the `$` or the `)` are actually word characters.  I'd like to do something equivalent though.   I came up with:

```
/([^\w\$\)_]|^)\$\(FOO\)([^\w\$\(_]|$)/$1FOO$2/
```

This seems messy (specifically I don't like the `$1` and `$2` in the regex.   I'm just wondering if there's a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: You first need to determine what characters would constitute a "boundary", then you can use [lookarounds](https://perldoc.pl/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) to assert what characters are allowed before and after. Negative lookarounds are usually best, because they also succeed when there are no remaining characters.

Comment: Is the question fully answered or does any residual question remain ?

Comment: Fully answered --  I wasn't aware of the look-around feature, which does pretty much exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using negative look-arounds makes the pattern a bit shorter and more readable, and gets rid of the capture groups:

```
s/(?<![\w$)])\$\(FOO\)(?![\w$(])/FOO/
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.